# Determine whether a const char* variable is a string literal at runtime?

Tags: linux, g++, c++17

I have the following:

```
int main() {
    std::string ss;
    std::cin >> ss;
    const char* foo = "literal";
    const char* r = ss.length() > 10 ? foo : ss.c_str();
    std::cout << someMagicFunction(r) << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to determine whether variable r is a string literal at runtime.  Is it possible (without taking so long e.g. 10ns)?  I am on Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What difference would it make? It shouldn't be mutated regardless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: There are situations in C (which is one of the tags on the question) where it is proper to convert a `const char *` to `char *` and to modify its contents. The `const` attribute does not mean the pointed-to object is immutable.

Comment: Did you mean to tag c **and** c++17?

Comment: No. Why would you want to?

Comment: This question seems to all but shout ["XY problem!"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @Bathsheba yes I put both c and c++17 as I don't mind my question to be solved by a c++17 technique.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes this is indeed an XY problem. Lol.  What I am trying to solve is to pass strings from one process to another process with the lowest latency (each cycle count) through shm in Linux with as little memory as possible (trashing the cache).  So by solving Y, it can solve X. Lol.

Comment: @HCSF *pass strings from one process to another process with the lowest latency* I don't see how knowing whether the string is a string literal helps that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle another process can look at the rodata section of the executable of the sender. So only address of the string needs to be sent if it is a literal.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot tell in a portable way.

And `const` doesn't help either. In C for example the type of `"foo"`, say is a `char[4]` type, which can *decay* to a `char*` pointer in certain situations, even though the character array is *read-only*.

Comment: Any non portable way if I am on CentOS 7 and GCC 7?

Comment: Not quickly no - you’d need to inspect the appropriate part of the compiled program.

Comment: @HCSF I am far away of being low-level expert, but maybe it is would be possible to guess whenever it is allocated on heap or on stack, based on address of `const char*`? Given that you can limit yourself to concrete kernel

Answer (score 0):

You can use overloading, you will be sure about variables, however `void function(char *r)` may receive a literal:

Might be a literal:

`void function(const char* r);`

Definitely, it is not a literal:

`void function(char *r);`

Comment: Overriding is not a *runtime* test, which is what the question requests. OP doesn't want to know if the argument to the function is a literal; they want to know if it is a variable (or other expression) whose value was initialised from a string literal.

Comment: Not true in c alas due to the type of say “foo” being char[4] which decays to char*. Although overloading is not possible in c either, so this is therefore a promising answer if it’s targetting c++ accepting that it’s a compile-time, not a run-time test.