# Is conditionally not modifying constant data undefined behavior in C?

Tags: c, constants, undefined-behavior

We have the following function:

```
void foo(int flag, void *ptr) {
    if (flag)
        strcpy(ptr, "Hello World");
    code_that_does_not_attempt_to_modify_data_pointed_to_by(ptr);
}
```

Would the following be valid:

```
const char *string_literal_ptr = "String literals are constant and may not be modified";
foo(0, string_literal_ptr);
```

We are passing a pointer to constant data to a function that *may* (but will not because we passed 0 as `flag`) modify the data pointed to by the pointer. Is this valid, given that at no point the program control reaches the point of modifying the constant data? Or is the mere existence of a non `const` pointer that points to `const` data invalid somehow?

Comment: Are you talking about *hypothetical code that doesn't actually exist?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey It exists now in the form of a StackOverflow question, and might exist in the future if by some stretch this situation arises

Comment: This is acceptable since the execution never reaches the undefined action. While it's true that undefined behavior can engage in time travel, it cannot create hypotheticals. (Otherwise, every program that used, say, the `/` operator would have a hypothetical division-by-zero.)

Comment: It's bad practice.  If you're careful (i.e. you pass the proper flag at the proper time), then yes, it will work (why wouldn't it?), but don't ever write code that actually looks like this.

Comment: I was considering the possibility that the compiler might see the `strcpy` and as such assume that the pointer may be modified and do something unexpected later on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50703025

Comment: A better approach: *return a pointer to the resulting string.*  Then you can write the function to be completely safe, because you won't be overwriting the original source.

Comment: You cannot pass a `const char*` to a function taking `void*`, it's a constraint violation - your code isn't valid C. Discussing UB in "not C" is pointless. You should make the parameter `const char*`.

Comment: @Lundin If the argument was `const char *` then I could not pass a `true` flag with a pointer to non-const data

Comment: @user16217248 I don't understand what you mean. The flag parameter has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Lundin The function should be able to modify the pointer, and either will or will not depending on the flag. Making the parameter `const char *` would not make sense if I *may* pass it to `strcpy`

Comment: @user16217248 That's true and the very reason why `strcpy` too uses const-correctness. You can however do an explicit conversion through a cast, in which case the various pointer conversion rules apply.

Comment: @Lundin So it will be valid C *if* I use an explicit cast instead of an implicit conversion?

Comment: Not if it still tries to modify a string literal.

Comment: @user16217248: So, it is the approach you describe (setting a flag to modify a function's behavior) that I am objecting to.  Functions should only do one thing, and if you only do that one thing, you won't have the problem described in your question.

Comment: Yeah, C actually doesn't mention what will happen if you "cast away" a const qualifier, other than "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @RobertHarvey The difference is that writing to const-qualified space or string literals is run-time UB. Passing an incompatible pointer type to a function is a constraint violation which must be detected at compile-time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Understood, this is not good practice and as such should be avoided, but I was just wondering if it were *valid* (which it seems it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `flag` is false then `strcpy(ptr, "Hello World");` is not evaluated, and the fact that `ptr` points to the data of a string literal is irrelevant.

If code on unexecuted paths could cause undefined behavior (due to its evaluation, not due to some grammar constraint that arises during translation), then C would break throughly, as tests for null pointers would not work:

```
if (p)
    Use pointer p to do something.
```

Comment: So the question now becomes, how does one properly identify non-writable strings?  Because passing a flag to do that is probably not the best of ideas.

Comment: But is there any undefined behavior as part of the (implicit?) cast from `const char *` to `void *`?

Comment: There is no implicit conversion to `void*` since that would be a constraint violation of 6.5.16.1. There are no implicit pointer conversions in C _at all_, save for the exceptions mentioned in 6.5.16.1. If the compiler generated a binary despite encountering non-conforming C, then the whole program is one big UB.

Comment: Conforming C Implementations are allowed to extend the language by waiving constraints, provided only that they issue at least one diagnostic if a constraint is violated.  The fact that there exists a Conforming C Implementation somewhere in the universe that accepts a program means it is a Conforming C Program, even if it isn't a Strictly Conforming C Program.

Comment: @user16217248: The conversion to `void *` occurs in the call to foo; it is not part of the conditionally executed code in the `if` and is a separate question, so, if you want details about that, you should post a new question. Passing a `const char *` for a `void *` parameter violates constraints in the C standard about qualifiers. The C implementation must diagnose the violation. The compiler may compile the program anyway, but then the standard does not define the behavior…

Comment: … If the compiler handles the issue by performing a conversion, then the conversion is defined by C 2018 6.3.2.3 1, which says “… A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.” No restrictions on qualifiers are stated. (This is an implicit conversion, not a cast. There is no such thing as an implicit cast; a cast is an explicit operator in source code.)

Comment: @supercat The question is explicitly about whether the code has UB or not. It has, just not where the OP thought it might be.

Comment: @Lundin: If a program uses extensions, the Standard would say nothing about its behavior, but an implementation which supports extensions should be expected to process it meaningfully anyhow.